# Bootstrap pop over form not submitting using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover, bootstrap-popover

I have a bootstrap popover form which has couple of input text fields and a submit button. The popover is displayed fine with the input text fields but when clicking the submit button the default action is not prevented at all. I have also tried to log in the form submit, but does not log anything at all. I think the reason has to do with popovers and how they are implemented in the first place.

```
<a href="#" id="popover" class="button blue">Create</a>
<div id="popover-head" class="hide"><h4>Create</h4></div>
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
    <form method="post">
        <p><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="tel" name="tel"></p>

        <input type="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

JQ:

```
$('#popover').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    title: function () {
        return $("#popover-head").html();
    },
    content: function () {
        return $("#popover-content").html();
    }
});

$('form').submit(function(){
    alert('form submitted');
    return false;
});
```

Anyone with a much clear idea can be of help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, that your `.popover-content` is actually cloned and injected into the DOM inside a `<div>`, the `.popover` itself. So your `submit()` is never binded to the form shown inside the popover, since it is added later. If you bind the event to `document` as a delegated event handler, then it will work with the form shown inside `.popover` too :

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function(){
    alert('form submitted');
    //prevent -> return false
    return false;
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/r1q6qjpo/**

---

**Note**: [`.hide` is deprecated](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix) :

> .hide is available, but it does not always affect screen readers and
>   is deprecated as of v3.0.1. Use .hidden or .sr-only instead.

Comment: It works, OK. But can you help me how can we make it with ajax? I have a button with type "button". If I make it "submit", then it works with post-back. How can I make with ajax request?

Comment: I solved my question.  "e.preventDefault();"  prevent to submit form if you manually call the ajax submit function.